# How to configure bare domain address in Route 53?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-route53

I want to configure a redirection from `example.com` to `www.example.com` (since CNAME is not allowed for top-level domains). How can I do this in AWS Route 53 (or any other DNS provider, in general)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [wwwizer.com](http://wwwizer.com/) for bare domain forwarding

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Think about it, I'll try to explain with an example. This is what you want:

```
example.com                   CNAME                 www
www                           A                     1.2.3.4
```

All traffic going to example.com would be redirected to www.example.com. Mail and other subdomains would be impacted.

To solve your problem, what you could do is the following:

```
example.com                   A                     1.2.3.4
www                           A                     1.2.3.4
```

Then you could set up a vhost in apache (if you are using that. I'm sure most software has a capability like this) that redirects all traffic that hits on example.com to www.example.com.